# Can I view mutiple spreadsheets at once in Excel 2010 without editing the Registry?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, standard-user

I have two Excel documents which I want to view in separate side-by-side windows.

The accepted answers for *[How can I make Excel documents open in different windows?](https://superuser.com/q/84190/358766)* and *[Open Worksheets In New Window In Excel 2010 Without Administrative Access](https://superuser.com/q/561185/358766)* both suggest using the *Registry Editor*. However, I'm using Excel on a work-provided PC, which means editing the registry isn't really an option.

**Is there a way to view multiple documents at once in Microsoft Excel 2010 *without* using the Registry Editor?**

[image: Two Excel windows side-by-side]

Comment: You can open multiple book and use View Arrange All in Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open your Books in the same Excel instance, just use Open in Excel Menu or Recent Books to open several Books.
To view it side by side use:

- View Tab (In Excel Ribbon)
- Arrange All (Window Group)
- Choose the convenient option

And you will see the multiple Books side by side